# How do I change the basic parameters of a Geometry in Three.js (for example, radius, number of vertices, etc.)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I create a tetrahedron of radius 3

```
   // create a tetrahedron
   var tetGeometry = new THREE.TetrahedronGeometry(3);
   var tetMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(
        {color: 0x20f020, transparent:true, opacity:0.6});
   tet = new THREE.Mesh(tetGeometry, tetMaterial);
   tet.name='tet';
   tet.castShadow = true;
```

Later, I want the tetrahedron to grow:

```
   // change hedron
   scene.getObjectByName('tet').radius = control.hedronRadius;
```

That doesn't work.

```
   // change vertices
   scene.getObjectByName('tet').detail = control.hedronVertices;
```

That doesn't work either.

```
   scene.getObjectByName('tet').verticesNeedUpdate;
```

And this doesn't help.

So how do I change the radius of a tetrahedron (or any Geometry) and how do I change the vertices.

In the documentation I see references to:

- Geometry

  - .dynamic
  - .morph
  - .verticesNeedUpdate
  - .scale

And also references to bones and skeletons and skinned meshes used to animate geometries.

How do I change these aspects of Geometries in general?
What's the most reasonable, suggested way then to grow the radius of a Tetrahedron, or change the number of vertices show it becomes a different number polyhedron?

Answer (score 1):

To change geometry you need to use:

```
morphTargets: true
```

[I've prepared an example using a tetrahedron as you mention in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Freeman555/81nozb73/1/).
Use sliders to change geometry.

To make some custom vertices and "fill" them by faces, you need to understand a lot of things from math, like; point, vector, etc.

[I've done 2 simple flat objects, triangle and square in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Freeman555/tro078at/).

I hope that you'll easy understand how it works in general.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at that!

Comment: So that was terrifically helpful for all sorts of reasons. Thank you.
Ultimately, I don't think it will help me if I want to add vertices, but it certainly helped me understand three.js better.

Comment: @Jerry, I've updated my answer. Please specify your question becouse right now you touches many topics.

Comment: Ah ha, thanks, I won't be able to look at this today, but I will over the weekend.